# What is the best practice for changing status of a record in database

Tags: sql, database, relational-database

My application is something like order tracking application.

An order is saved in a order table for 300 items. If we process whole items from 1st step then I can place a field of status telling that this order is in 1st step to track the orders and make them available for next steps.

But If machine of step one has capacity of processing 150 items only then I have to mention that 150 items of that order are in step 2 and 150 items are in step 1. And for this I am planning to have tables of each step and save data to respective table.

Order Table: order = 001, items=300 ...

Step 1 table: order = 001, items = 150 ...

Step 2 table: order = 001, items = 150 ...

and so on

My confusion is only this that whether I am doing it right or not. This could be case with many users and how they handle that? Am I doing it right or just overloading the database.

**Tables:**
Below is my tables structure, that I have made. Lot, LotOrder and lotorderdetail tables are related to orders and WindingMain and Dyeing are steps.
[image]

Comment: Please give the structure of your order and/or order_item tables. Are there product references? Why would you say 150 are in step 2 because a machine cannot handle more than a certain limit? Seems strange to me that step 1 is then just skipped for some items. Your question is not clear.

Comment: no it means that machine will first process 150 items and then its entry will be entered in system that 150 items of that order is processed in step1. And then remaining 150 will be processed in step1 machine. I have to keep record of items that 150 are passed on to step2 and 150 are available to process in step1.

Comment: Do you only have the number of items in the table, not a record per item? And can you please post the structure of your tables (I asked before)?

Comment: Please expand on "This could be case with many users and how they handle that?" Eg do you mean, users who placed orders? They can look at their order status by an interface implemented by SELECT ... WHERE user = *user*. You can use a DBMS's security features to do this.

Comment: Sorry for the huge delay, @trincot I have updated my question.

Comment: Which is the table and column name where you store the item count? Are there multiple places where you store this?

Comment: in lot order detail => cones, in windingmain and dyeing => Produced cones.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when you have items that are in orders, you'll have something like this (if you don't, it would be very helpful if you can explain your database structure):

**items**

- id
- name
- price

**orders**

- id
- customer_id

**order_items**

- id (optional)
- order_id
- item_id
- quantity
- price

The *order_items* table contains the "lines" of your orders. If you wanted to record fulfilment steps for each order line, you could add a column *step*.

For example, I might have an order for 100 pens and 500 pencils. Your data structure would be able to reflect that the pens are in Step 1, while the pencils are in Step 2.

If you had some pens in Step 1 and some in Step 2, you could split it into two order_items.

The key point is that you generally don't want to make a set of tables for different values of something (e.g. step), when you can use a column instead.

Comment: No you can say That I have a order of 500 pencils with red color and pencil should be sharped. Lets say step1 is coloring the pencil and step2 is sharpening it. But coloring machine can color only 150 pencils at a time. After coloring 150 pencils system should know that user can sharp 150 pencils and color 350 pencils.

Comment: Okay, well in the structure I proposed, you can do that by splitting the order_items, so your order would start off with 500 pencils in step 1, then would have 150 in step 2 and 350 in step 1.

Comment: If you prefer not to mess with the order like that, you could add a table called something like fulfillment, which stores the order_item_id, quantity and step. You could write a row whenever a step is completed for some items. This is a more robust way to do it.

Comment: If your orders are only ever for one thing, you'd ditch the orders table and call order_items orders.

Answer (score 0):

**Re steps**

> Order Table: order = 001, items=300 ...
>   Step 1 table: order = 001, items = 150 ...
>   Step 2 table: order = 001, items = 150 ...

Your current design represents certain situations in certain ways. But there is no problem having one table with step as a column:

```
// order [order] is for [items] items ...
Order(order,items,...)

// order [order] has [items] items in step [step]
Step(order,items,step...)
```

This has the benefit that now your queries are not limited to either using literal step numbers or using metadata to deal with multiple steps.

**Re users**

If orders are placed by users then you should add another column:

```
// order [order] placed by user [user] is for [items] items ...
Order(user,order,items,...)

// order [order] placed by user [user] has [items] items in step [step]
Step(user,order,items,step,...)
```

There's no "overloading" a DBMS by having many columns or many rows. That is what they are designed for. If anything, most have more have space and time limitations for a large number of tables rather than columns or rows.

**PS Re finding & judging designs**

Every table has a *meaning* that is a *predicate*: a statement parameterized by column names. Eg the code comments above. A row plus a predicate gives a *proposition*: a statement. The rows that make a true proposition go in the table. We must find sufficient predicates each with a base table to express everything relevant about an application situation.

- if multiple predicates/tables differ only by a common value then you can add a parameter/column and use a single predicate/table
- if a complex predicate/table can be more clearly expressed in terms of the AND/JOIN of simpler ones then you can split up the predicates/tables
- if you have one or more predicates containing the same expression then you can define another predicate to express the originals more simply
- you can define views and computed columns to avoid redundant and contradictory data

Let's focus on just order, items and condition. Note that it is still difficult to query about parts that are either in a step or unprocessed (or finished):

```
//    order [order] has [items] items in step [condition]
   OR order [order] has [items] items unprocessed AND [condition] = unprocessed
Condition(order,items,condition)
```

Or to be able to do arithmetic on all conditions, not just steps:

```
//     order [order] has [items] items in step [state]
   OR order [order] has [items] items unprocessed AND [state] = 0
State(order,items,state)
```

Another thing you can do is *define* what state means in terms of conditions and steps:

```
//  item [item] is in state [state] means
        item [item] is in step [state]
    OR item [item] is unprocessed AND [state] = 0

// order [order] has [items] items in state [state]
State(order,items,state)
```

You can also define State by a view. Its defining query expression is for a table whose predicate is exactly the meaning of the definition above.

The tradeoff: You can have separate tables for unprocessed vs in-process items where querying about condition is more difficult. Or you can have one table for unprocessed and in-process items but the definitions are more complicated.