# Relationalship design in PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, relational-database

I'm using PostgreSQL, I have created statements table in my database and insert info related by below code:

```
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS statements (statement_id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, statement_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, code INT NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY (code) REFERENCES companies_list (code))")

statement_name = ["balance_sheet", "income_statement", "cash_flow"]
```

After execution it gave me result below:

```
 statement_id |  statement_name  | code 
--------------+------------------+---------
        1     | balance_sheet    |    1111
        2     | Income_statement |    1111
        3     | cash_flow        |    1111
        4     | balance_sheet    |    2222
```

I intiated 3 statements for each company code. companies codes in the table  is the full list, some of those codes (in banks sector) need to be using different statements for banks only ( balance sheet "Banks", income statement "Banks", and cash flow "Banks").
what's the best solution to do it?.. do i need to make more statements names ( i.e. balance_sheets_banks ) or should i include all those codes of banks in a list and assign it some how ? either answer how can i do it?

The reason I'm asking this question cause in later step i'm creating a table ( named statement_items ) it will include items of each statement, find it below:

```
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS statement_items (statement_row_id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, statement_id INT NOT NULL, row_order INT NOT NULL, row_title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY (statement_id) REFERENCES statements (statement_id))")
```

After execturion it will give me:

```
  statement_row_id | statement_id | row_order |   row_title 
 ------------------+--------------+-----------+----------------
         1         |       1      |     1     | Current Assets
         2         |       2      |     1     |      Sales
```

So in the end how to solve the first point above and how to implement the change on the next table ?

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood the question, you're creating a table of financial statements and want to know whether you should treat "banking" statements the same as other statements or as a "special case" of some other statement types.

In my experience, "special-case" processing adds a layer of complexity and difficulty in maintenance which is rarely justifiable, and so as an experienced maintenance programmer my instinct is to avoid special cases whenever possible. I would simply create separate records for "balance sheet" and "balance sheet (bank)" &c. &c.

I'm less clear on the second part of your question, but I'll give it a go anyway and you can correct me if I'm off the track: In the absence of contradicting requirements, I would give each statement its own set of line items, independent of the line items on other statements, the same way that one invoice's line items are independent of those of other invoices. It might be possible *if necessary* to share line items between statements, but I would need to see a convincing use case before attempting it.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently a statement name is the name of a format for a statement. Banks have bank-style statements. Non-banks have non-bank-style statements. Is there anything about the situation that's asymmetrical? Is there a need to parameterize either kind of statement that would suggest a different structure for bank or non-bank? If not, just have statement names for use in banks and non-banks:

```
Company(company_code, ...)
    PK (company_code)
Statement(statement_name, company_code, ...)
    PK (statement_name, company_code)
    FK (company_code) to Company)
Row(statement_name, company_code, row_number, ...)
    PK (statement_name, company_code, row_number)
    FK (company_code) to Company)
    FK(statement_name) to Statement)
```

Assign bank & non-bank statements to banks & non-banks as appropriate. Since the database doesn't actually distinguish banks vs non-banks, there isn't any redundancy or possible inconsistency. (Just DBMS-undetectably inappropriate statement assignments for a company of a given type.)

But if you want to parameterize company and statement queries by company type (bank vs non-bank or whatever) then associate company type with companies and statements:

```
Company(company_code, company_type, ...)
    PK (company_code)
    UNIQUE NOT NULL (company_code, company_type)
Statement(statement_name, company_code, company_type, ...)
    PK (statement_name, company_code, company_type)
    FK (company_code, company_type) to Company
Row(statement_name, company_type, row_number, ...)
    PK (statement_name, company_type, row_number)
    FK(statement_name, company_type) to Statement
```

A statement must agree in company type with its company. An easy way to enforce this is a FK from Statement to Company on both company_code and company_type. Then SQL requires that every FK target be declared as PK or UNIQUE NOT NULL. We can identify statements by their name and company type.

You don't need additional CK/PK surrogate id columns in either design as far as the database is concerned. You can add them; but if you use id values in other base tables unaccompanied by their respective natural key values then it can be difficult to know whether or how to constrain them with other ids.

Re finding appropriate designs see [this recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34447216/3404097).